# Retrieve object from select drop down list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

I am trying to return a meetingSpace object from the last form group in this razor page:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Booking.Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Booking.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Booking.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Booking.Name"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Booking.Start">Start</label>
        <input asp-for="Booking.Start" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Booking.Start"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Booking.Duration">Duration</label>
        <input asp-for="Booking.Duration" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Booking.Duration"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Booking.MeetingSpace">Room</label>
        <select data-value="true" data-va-required="The meeting space field is required" id="MeetingSpace.Id" name="MeetingSpace.Name">
            @foreach (var meetingSpace in Model.meetingSpaces)
            {
                <option value="meetingSpace">@meetingSpace.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

I am unsure how set this select dropdown to return the value to the Booking.MeetingSpace property. I can see the list of meetingSpace objects in the drop down but after selecting an option the meetingSpace field in the created/edited object is not returned as with the other properties in the form. I have also tried the same using the Booking.MeetingSpaceId int as well but it is still not populated after submission of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be a binding problem try to change the name attribute value like this:

```
<select data-value="true" data-va-required="The meeting space field is required" id="Booking.MeetingSpace.Id" name="Booking.MeetingSpace.Name">
            @foreach (var meetingSpace in Model.meetingSpaces)
            {
                <option value="@meetingSpace.Id">@meetingSpace.Name</option>
            }
</select>
```

also  option value should start with @ to be recognized.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I was struggling to understand some of this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). You were right and after making your changes I noticed that the selected id was being saved in the Booking.MeetingSpace.Id property. I changed `name="Booking.MeetingSpace.Id"` to `name="Booking.MeetingSpaceId"` and got the result I desired thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Also look at these docs for more info on using select taghelper in .net core : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-select-tag-helper .